# Get date between tags using sed or awk

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

Given the following bit of text, how would i go about returning just the date with an awk or sed command?

```
<span class="MyClass" style="font-family: Arial">01/09/2005</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '{print $3}'
```

HTH Chris

Answer (score 1):

With sed you could do:

```
sed 's/<span.*>\(.*\)<\/span>.*/\1/'
```

Note that it is generally a bad idea parsing html with sed (or awk)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1'
```

seems to work for your case

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
<<<'<span class="MyClass" style="font-family: Arial">01/09/2005</span>' sed 's_.*\(../../....\).*_\1_'
01/09/2005
```